# The main thread does not wait for another thread to finish execution

Tags: android, synchronization, java-threads

Right now I'm facing a problem which I cannot solve, There's a thread which I need to fill two arrays with specific data, and then use these two arrays later, however, my main thread does not wait for the thread to finish and I don't know why!! 
Here is my code

```
private void loadingData(){
    Thread myThread=new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            getNationalities();
            getReligions();
        }
    });

    myThread.start();
    try {
        myThread.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    loadingIcon.show();

    while(myThread.isAlive()){}

    //Here I'm using the two filled arrays
    nationalitySpinner();
    religionSpinner();

    loadingIcon.hide();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't run asynchronous Networking or time-consuming operation in the in main thread it will freeze the UI.

Try to use `AsyncTask`, in `OnPostExecute` of `AsyncTask` you can update in UI

Example :

```
private void loadingData(){
    new MyTask().execute();

}

class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        loadingIcon.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

        getNationalities();
        getReligions();

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);

        nationalitySpinner();
        religionSpinner();

        loadingIcon.hide();

    }
}
```

For more info refer [Processes and threads](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html), [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Comment: can you give me an example how to implement it?

Comment: @AhmedKhairy, Updated my answer

Comment: it got me Null Pointer Exception and I don't know why is that, maybe the arrays are not yet filled? but I don't know how, But i will be more clear with you, I want my UI to wait until the data gets filled, instead of being filled infront of the end user, do you get me?

Comment: I don't have your complete code, So I don't know which one is giving null pointer exception. But for your question, If you want to wait till asynchronous call ends you can use AsyncTask in Android, I added the reference in my answer have a look. For Null pointer issue, you can ask in Another question because while people searching for the same answer again it will mislead them.

Comment: nationalityspinner() gives a null pointer exception because the array is not yet filled

Comment: ok, may be you can initialize the array and you can fill that, instead of declaring that as null.